# firejail: wine regedit doesn't save changes

Tags: wine, firejail

Update2:
Registry's changes **actually** saved. But for entries that will not be permanently stored (that be reset if, for example run `wineboot`), after `regedit` (with `firejail`) is closed, those entries are reset to default.

Example:
If I add a new `String value` entry called `test`. The change is saved.
If I modify `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>Hardware>Description>System>CentralProcessor>0>VendorIdentifier` from `AuthenticAMD` to `None`, it does not works with `firejail`.

Without `firejail`, the change is saved, but if I run `wineboot`, it reset to default.

---

Update:
It seems that changes actually wrote to disk, while modifying registry with `regedit` (with `filejail`), I open another `regedit`, and saw that data was modified.
But, after close `regedit`, the registry is reset.

---

I'm using `firejail` version 0.9.56 (default package from Mageia).
I have no problem running `wine` with `firejail`, except when I want to modify registry.
Without `firejail`, there's no problem, but when I run `wine` with `firejail` all modifications revert back to default.

Here is my `firejail` wine profile:

```
# Firejail profile for wine
# Description: A compatibility layer for running Windows programs
# This file is overwritten after every install/update
# Persistent local customizations
include /etc/firejail/wine.local
# Persistent global definitions
include /etc/firejail/globals.local

noblacklist ${HOME}/.Steam
noblacklist ${HOME}/.local/share/Steam
noblacklist ${HOME}/.local/share/steam
noblacklist ${HOME}/.steam
noblacklist ${HOME}/.wine
# with >=llvm-4 mesa drivers need llvm stuff
noblacklist /usr/lib/llvm*

include /etc/firejail/disable-common.inc
include /etc/firejail/disable-devel.inc
include /etc/firejail/disable-interpreters.inc
include /etc/firejail/disable-programs.inc

caps.drop all
netfilter
nodvd
nogroups
nonewprivs
noroot

#############
blacklist /media
blacklist /mnt

noblacklist ${HOME}/.wine
whitelist ${HOME}/.wine
noblacklist /tmp/.wine-*
whitelist /tmp/.wine-*

include /etc/firejail/whitelist-common.inc
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the terminal when you try to run regedit?

Comment: There's a error message:
```Error: cannot read UID_MIN and/or GID_MIN from /etc/login.defs, using 1000 by default```

Comment: I created user for running ``wine`` with ``firejail`` has UID 555

Comment: Ok. Maybe try noblacklisting /etc/login.defs?

Comment: It does not work, also this error still appears.

Comment: try it with `firejail --noprofile`, which will set up the least restrictive sandbox possible. If it works with that, then you know the issue is something in your .profile file and you can use a process of elimination to figure it out.

Comment: Yes, I ran with ``--noprofile`` and still have problem.
I've update my question, only entries that temporarily stored (if I do not run ``wineboot``) are not saved.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, it does not really solve this problem of running `wine` with `firejail`, but it solved problem that I need changes of registry take effect on other applications running inside the same sanbox.

My solution is:

1. Install `Autohotkey`.
2. Make a script, such as:

   ```
   ^k::
   Run, regedit

   ^j::
   Run, other_application.exe
   ```